# slideshow inside header.tpl

Tags: module, header, positioning, slideshow, opencart

I am using Opencart 1.5.3.1 with custom theme.
Having problem with positioning the slideshow inside the header itself (i.e. in header.tpl).
I have learned the way to make new position for slideshow module, but it is only showing it up before or after the header - and I need it to be inside of it.
Once I made to be before or after the header, I tried to echo it inside the header.tpl file but it gives me the message:
Warning: Undefined variable...

Anybody can help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules cannot be placed inside the header, it is purposely built this way. Each section of the page has its own controller and usually a model. The reason you are getting a variable error is the sideshow controller is not loaded, only the header controller and model is.

Without changing the core of the module integration you would be better trying to implement the slide show controller in the header controller.

Comment: you were absolutely right. I have modified the core files and made it work ok. Thank you anyway.